# Visual Studio Code: Unable to locate phpcs

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

I am facing this issue in Visual Studio Code.  I have already tried reinstalling the phpcs extension but still facing this issue.

[image: this is the image]

> Unable to locate phpcs
>
> Please add `phpcs` to your global path or use the composer dependency manager to install it in your project locally in Visual studio Code

Answer (score 117, accepted):

I had the same issue, I did the following to fix it:

1. Install the phpcs by using composer with `composer global require squizlabs/php_codesniffer`
2. Press `Command + ,` (Click Code -> Preferences -> Settings)
3. Select User Settings and locate '`PHP CodeSniffer`'
4. Scroll to '`Executatble Path`' and put

   /Users/your-username/.composer/vendor/bin/phpcs

This fixed the issue for me, I hope it does for you too. Cheers!

Comment: This work for me, you need had the packet 'php-xml' installed.
And the  'Executatble Path' can change to:
/Users/your-username/.config/composer/vendor/bin/phpcs

Comment: "phpcs.standard": "PSR2",
    "phpcs.enable": true,
    "php.validate.executablePath": "/usr/bin/php7.3",
    "phpcs.executablePath": "/home/<username>/.composer/vendor/squizlabs/php_codesniffer/bin/phpcs",
    "phpcs.autoConfigSearch": true,

Comment: Executatble path for those using Debian Linux or based on it: /home/your-user/.config/composer/vendor/squizlabs/php_codesniffer/bin/phpcs

Comment: I don't know what I did wrong but I had to use this path:
/Users/<user name>/AppData/Roaming/Composer/vendor/bin/phpcs

Comment: Worked on mac. Thank you.

Comment: to find your phpcs location, type `where phpcs` in your cmd

Answer (score 31):

open the project in the terminal and run this command

```
composer global require squizlabs/php_codesniffer
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 15):

I think uninstalling it does not solve the issue.

i had the same issue. So,

1. Go to extensions and install the plugin...."phpcs".
2. Search for the extension if you had install it.
3. Disable the extension.

it resolved the issue in my VS code.

Answer (score 15):

On Debian based systems run as root:

```
apt-get install php-codesniffer
```

Comment: Works for Ubuntu 18.04 also

Answer (score 10):

My solution without the need to install php_codesniffer globally.

Just go to VSCode settings and define the local path `./vendor/squizlabs/php_codesniffer/bin/phpcs`

[image]

Or you can set the path directly in your `settings.json`

```
"phpcs.executablePath": "./vendor/squizlabs/php_codesniffer/bin/phpcs"
```

Answer (score 9):

From a [GitHub comment](https://git.io/fxNfC).

> If someone still needs help about this "Unable to locate phpcs ..."
>   error message, try this:   you just need to install `phpcs` globally
>   via Composer.
>
> 1. Install Composer from [this resource](https://getcomposer.org/download/) if you don't have it,
> 2. After Composer is installed, open a command prompt wherever you want and run this command
>
>    ```
>    composer global require squizlabs/php_codesniffer
>    ```

Answer (score 7):

In my case and in Windows 10, composer located at:

```
C:\Users\{user_name}\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin\
```

and when i added this to VSCode settings at PHP CodeSniffer section this solve my problem.

Comment: Didn't work on my **Windows 10** i had to add `phpcs` at the end like the following:

`C:\Users\{user_name}\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin\phpcs`

Comment: This is what worked for me. Files/Preferences/Settings. Search for PHP CodeSniffer. Add the path above to the executable path.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and i did this to fix it in **my windows**:

1. You will Download the Composer (From [here](https://getcomposer.org/download/))
2. Go to Vs code and open your terminal and run this command

   ```
   composer global require squizlabs/php_codesniffer
   ```
3. Go to (settings--> User Settings), then search **PHP CodeSniffer**
4. Scroll to **Executatble Path**  and type

   ```
   \Users\{user_name}\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin\phpcs
   ```

   and restart VS code.

This works For me, I hope it Works for you too :D

Answer (score 2):

paste the following in your terminal for system-wide installation

```
composer global require squizlabs/php_codesniffer
```

This stopped the error message from popping up in mine.

Comment: Thanks for joining StackOverflow! Unfortunately, an identical answer to this one has already been posted.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else still struggling with this on **Windows 11**, I had to put **double backslashes** in the path, and link to the `*.bat` file instead (for both phpcs and phpcbf), in `settings.json`:

```
C:\\Users\\user-name\\AppData\\Roaming\\Composer\\vendor\\squizlabs\\php_codesniffer\\bin\\phpcs.bat
```

I had run all the global installation commands, etc, as described by all the other comments but still no joy in VS Code. I also tried without the phpcs filename (ie, just ending in `\\bin`), and ending in phpcs without the file extension, but those didn't work. I had also set the PATH to phpcs and phpcbf in my **environment variables**.

Comment: To add to the Windows weirdness, if you're using WSL2 with Ubuntu, you might need to use the non ".bat" files, but still link to C:\\Usres\\ etc" , at least I did. Man, I hate Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Install [PHP Sniffer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=wongjn.php-sniffer)
instead of [phpcs](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ikappas.phpcs)

***PHP Sniffer*** worked on the fly without any extra configuration

***phpcs*** could not recognize my commands, despite a configured PATH, Composer & PHPCS installed.

The commands were recognized in the terminal, but not by the plugin
(under windows 10)

Answer (score 1):

I had this same error and I noticed that phpcs was working from the command line but not working in vscode. I had to read the linter.js file (of the vscode extension) to see where this error is coming from. This fix is more of an info.

So, to fix this: First, run the command `phpcs --version` and check if the command does not print any warning or error before outputting a line similar to `PHP_CodeSniffer version x.x.x (stable) by Squiz (HTTP://www.squiz.net)`.

If any error or warning (usually unrelated to phpcs) is thrown before the line showing the  phpcs version, please go fix that warning or error first. According to linter.js, it expects that the first output (when phpcs.bat is executed) must start with the `PHP_CodeSniffer version` string. Thus, If anything should print before the **PHP_CodeSniffer version ....**, then it throws the error.

So, You MUST fix any warning or error printed before the phpcs version if you want phpcs to work in VSCode. I hope this fix works for you. cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with all these answers and I think it may be confusing to someone who is new to composer on Windows 10

This gives you better understanding of paths and Windows Environment Variables settings. However, it also includes installing php7 and integration with cakephp which you might want to skip and focus on (Composer and phpcs)

I found the fix at https://www.bravo-kernel.com/2017/03/installing-php7-composer-and-codesniffer-on-windows10-for-vscode/

And it had everything I needed to get phpcs working perfectly.

PROCEEDURE:

1. Download Composer for Windows 10 [Here](https://getcomposer.org/download/)
2. Install Composer on Windows 10
3. Open Command Prompt(cmd.exe) and type "composer" and hit the enter key (Just search the windows start for "cmd")

   ```
    Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.1165]
    (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

    C:\Users\systemuser>composer
   ```

If composer is properly installed you will get a response with something like this

```
       ______
      / ____/___  ____ ___  ____  ____  ________  _____
     / /   / __ \/ __ `__ \/ __ \/ __ \/ ___/ _ \/ ___/
    / /___/ /_/ / / / / / / /_/ / /_/ (__  )  __/ /
    \____/\____/_/ /_/ /_/ .___/\____/____/\___/_/
                /_/
    Composer version 2.1.5 2021-07-23 10:35:47

    Usage:
    command [options] [arguments]

    Options:
      -h, --help                     Display this help message
      -q, --quiet                    Do not output any message
      -V, --version                  Display this application version
      --ansi                     Force ANSI output
  --no-ansi                  Disable ANSI output
  -n, --no-interaction           Do not ask any interactive question
  --profile                  Display timing and memory usage information
  --no-plugins               Whether to disable plugins.
   -d, --working-dir=WORKING-DIR  If specified, use the given directory as 
    working directory.
    --no-cache                 Prevent use of the cache
   -v|vv|vvv, --verbose           Increase the verbosity of messages: 1 for 
    normal output, 2 for more verbose output and 3 for debug

    Available commands:
    (It continues)
```

4. If you do not intend to change the default directory you can now install phpcs otherwise you can use instructions from the link above to set a new executable path. The default composer directory is

   ```
    C:/Users/systemuser/AppData/Roaming/Composer
   ```

Now in Command prompt add the following command (Global installation):

```
    composer global require squizlabs/php_codesniffer
```

Here is what it will look like:

```
    C:\Users\systemuser>composer global require squizlabs/php_codesniffer
    Changed current directory to C:/Users/systemuser/AppData/Roaming/Composer
    Using version ^3.6 for squizlabs/php_codesniffer
    ./composer.json has been updated
    Running composer update squizlabs/php_codesniffer
    Loading composer repositories with package information
    Updating dependencies
    Nothing to modify in lock file
    Writing lock file
    Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
    Nothing to install, update or remove
    Generating autoload files

    C:\Users\systemuser>
```

Note: Nothing installed because I already installed phpcs. Also you can see that composer switched to the default directory, if this doesn't happen you need to navigate to the appropriate directory with "cd newpath" before installing phpcs:

```
    C:\Users\systemuser>cd AppData\Roaming\Composer
```

The result is:

```
    C:\Users\systemuser\AppData\Roaming\Composer>
```

You have completed the installation so verify the app path by navigating the path

[image: C:\Users\systemuser\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin]

Now you can copy the link to the phpcs file and paste in VSCode (If you changed your composer bin path then you need to copy the appropriate directory). It should look like this

```
    C:\Users\sytemuser\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin\phpcs
```

[image: C:\Users\systemuser\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin\phpcs]

Now phpcs should work fine after installing the extension!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on my Mac in Visual Studio Code (I used PEAR to install PHPCS).
I do not know why but PHPCS couldn't find autoload.php of CodeSniffer.
You can try to type on terminal command line:

```
$ phpcs
```

I got an error:

> Warning: include_once(PHP/CodeSniffer/autoload.php): failed to open
>   stream: No such file or directory in /Users/david/pear/bin/phpcs on
>   line 14
>
> Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'PHP/CodeSniffer/autoload.php'
>   for inclusion (include_path='.:') in /Users/david/pear/bin/phpcs on
>   line 14

**Solution:**

Open Pear Bin folder in your user folder, e.g. in my case: `/Users/david/pear/bin/` in Finder,

Find `phpcs` file inside and edit it (e.g. in Visual Studio Code :),

You will find these lines there:

```
if (is_file(__DIR__.'/../autoload.php') === true) {
    include_once __DIR__.'/../autoload.php';
} else {
    include_once 'PHP/CodeSniffer/autoload.php';
}
```

Add two new lines there with the proper location of CodeSniffer/autoload.php file (place it before `} else {` line and modify the path according to your needs - replace "david" with your user name...):

```
} else if (is_file('/users/david/pear/share/pear/PHP/CodeSniffer/autoload.php')) {
    include_once '/users/david/pear/share/pear/PHP/CodeSniffer/autoload.php';
```

So the final code of the condition is:

```
if (is_file(__DIR__.'/../autoload.php') === true) {
    include_once __DIR__.'/../autoload.php';
} else if (is_file('/users/david/pear/share/pear/PHP/CodeSniffer/autoload.php')) {
    include_once '/users/david/pear/share/pear/PHP/CodeSniffer/autoload.php';
} else {
    include_once 'PHP/CodeSniffer/autoload.php';
}
```

Then save it and restart Visual Studio Code. That's it.

Comment: This looked promising but I still get an error. My phpcs will run on the CLI just not in VSCode.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Drupal, the solutions is specify coding standards.
So create phpcs.xml and enable the next options.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
"phpcs.standard": "PSR2",
"phpcs.enable": true,
"phpcs.executablePath": "/home/<username>/.config/composer/vendor/squizlabs/php_codesniffer/bin/phpcs",
"phpcs.autoConfigSearch": true
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the best answer

In my case(in Windows 10), the composer located at:

```
C:\Users\user-name\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\squizlabs\php_codesniffer\bin
```

Answer (score 0):

Filling in the `Executatble Path` in VSCode settings for PHPCS will work if you have it installed through composer globally. You can also set it for individual project workspaces if you have a PHPCS configured for your project.   To do that, create a workspace file through `File->Save Workspace As` and place this in your setting object:

```
"phpcs.enable": true,
"phpcs.standard": "WordPress", // or another standard
"phpcs.executablePath": "relative/path/to/vendor/bin/phpcs",
"phpcs.showWarnings": true,
"phpcs.composerJsonPath": "composer.json",
"phpcs.errorSeverity": 5,
"php.suggest.basic": true
```

[Here is a link](https://tommcfarlin.com/php-codesniffer-per-project/) to a resource describing the process more in depth.

Answer (score -1):

You stated that you already uninstalled it, so i'm assuming your trying to get rid of the extension and error.

**How to fix:**

1. Uninstall extension.
2. Delete the entire phpcs folder from the VS Code folder.

**From the VS Code Docs:**

**Q:** Where are extensions installed?

**A:** Depending on your platform, the global location is in the following folders:

```
Windows %USERPROFILE%\.vscode\extensions

Mac ~/.vscode/extensions

Linux ~/.vscode/extensions
```