# phpcs: Referenced sniff "WordPress" does not exist

Tags: phpcs

I've installed `phpcs` by following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55889259/877797), and added the following to my Visual Code `settings.json`:

```
{
    "phpcs.enable": true,
    "phpcs.composerJsonPath": "wp-content/themes/wprig/composer.json",
    "phpcs.standard": "WordPress",
    "phpcs.executablePath": "/Users/Chris/.composer/vendor/bin/phpcs",
}
```

However, when I edit a PHP file in a WordPress theme, Visual Code displays an error @ bottom right:

```
phpcs: Referenced sniff "WordPress" does not exist
```

If I run `phpcs -i` I receive: `The installed coding standards are PEAR, Zend, PSR2, MySource, Squiz, PSR1 and PSR12`.

How do I install the WordPress coding standard for `phpcs` please?

**Update**: I followed the steps @ [this tutorial](https://tommcfarlin.com/php-codesniffer-in-visual-studio-code/), specifically running:

```
./vendor/bin/phpcs --config-set installed_paths /Applications/AMPPS/www/example.local/wp-content/themes/dev/wpcs
```

(I receive a positive confirmation after this). And I add `"phpcs.standard": "WordPress",` to VS Code's `settings.json`, however the error remains, even after restarting VS Code.

I have the WordPress coding standards directory @ `/Applications/AMPPS/www/example.local/wp-content/themes/dev/wpcs`.

Help appreciated.

Comment: Did you get this working?

Comment: Not yet @AndreVitorio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have cloned wpcs @ WordPress project.
Try to clone wpcs into another dir e.g.

```
git clone -b master https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress-Coding-Standards.git /Applications/AMPPS/www/wpcs
```

and add its path to the PHP_CodeSniffer configuration

```
phpcs --config-set installed_paths /Applications/AMPPS/www/wpcs
```

Dot't forget to remove `/Applications/AMPPS/www/example.local/wp-content/themes/dev/wpcs` from themes dir.